# Prevent WooCommerce Catalog Images from Resizing

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 2.X with Zurb Foundation 5.X. Here's what my basic layout looks like on desktop:

[image]

...which is fine by me. Problem is, upon viewport resizing, the product images shrink, instead of collapsing under each other, resulting in a crammed, ugly layout like this:

[image]

This is the output of the "out of the box" code.

I've made no modifications to content-product.php or woocommerce.css. When I modify content-product.php to wrap each iteration of the loop in "large-3 columns" -- which one would think would be the correct solution since we're using Foundation -- the output becomes:

[image]

It seems to me that the

elements are resizing to 22.05% of their respective  elements, just as the CSS below declares:

```
/* Product loops */

.products ul, ul.products {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none outside;
    clear:both;
    .clearfix();
    li {
        list-style:none outside;
    }
}

ul.products {
    li.product {
        float:left;
        margin: 0 3.8% 2.992em 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 22.05%;
        margin-left: 0;
        a img {
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
            display:block;
            margin: 0 0 8px;
            .box_shadow(0,1px,2px,0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
            .transition();
        }
    }
    li.first {
        clear:both;
    }
    li.last {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

No matter how I modify the image size percentages, I cannot increase their size. Ultimately, I want my mobile layout to look something like a nice, stacked, fluid layout, like so:

[image]

Seems so easy, yet here I am, 5 hours and no love later. Any help greatly appreciated!